# BigQuery errors with rateLimitExceeded even not having 100 concurrent jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Over the past few days, many of the requests made to Big Query are failing with:

> Exceeded rate limits: too many concurrent queries for this project_and_region. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas

When I go to the documentation, I get that this error is related to running too many concurrent jobs in Big Query (the limit is 100). When I go to Big Query admin -> monitoring and check the job concurrency metric, at no point in time there were more than 50 concurrent tasks running (seeing the chart for the past few hours with 5-minute intervals), even though there were failures in that meantime.

I'm also checking the tasks that failed thru the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS table, for getting accurate timestamps on the failed tasks, and checking the concurrency for that timestamps on the admin monitoring.

We're not using queues in our environment for now.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could be a BigQuery issue. Did you try to contact the support?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere not yet, I was hoping it was a straightforward thing, but seems I'll have to contact them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons for this error is the slots reservation already maxed out while the tasks were running, there are quotas applied to reservations per region.

For EU maximum number of slots that can be purchased - 2000 slots

For US maximum number of slots that can be purchased - 4000 slots

You can check the chart of the reservation or slot usage and see if it maxes out while the concurrent tasks are running. Even if the concurrent tasks did not exceed 100 but the reservation is maxed out during the process, you will encounter this error.

You can learn more about the quotas of reservations per region using the link below:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#reservations

If you think you did not exceed this limit, you can also reach out to google cloud support, so they can assist you on this problem.

https://cloud.google.com/support

Comment: Thanks for the answer @karlvkva! Yes, during the errors my purchased slots are all in use. But then, this error description is misleading since it's not due to concurrency, it's about slot capacity... To solve this, I must buy more slots, correct?

Comment: Yes you can increase your reservation or you can also try using enabling query queues. 

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-queues

Comment: Query queues will just queue your query whenever the maximum concurrency is reached. I've attached the documentation above.

Comment: Yes, I was also considering enabling queues. Thanks!